# Best SMPS wattage required for the below config?

Tags: cpu, power-supply, productivity

We are planing to assemble a file server of the following configuration.

1. Intel S2400SC2 Motherboard.
2. Xeon 2407 Processor x 2 (Dual Processors)
3. 8gb x 8 ECC DDR3 RAM
4. One 2 TB Seagate HDD.
5. 8 cabinet fans fitted for NZXT Switch 810 Cabinet.

Our question is is CoolerMaster 850 Watts power supply enough for our machine?

Please suggest the best brand and wattage of SMPS we have to buy for our system.

Should we go for 400W or  500W or 600W or 700W or 850W?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's *more* than enough. It's not like you are running a power-hungry graphics card in there or even multiple hard drives.

Each of those 2 CPUs will use around [80W](http://ark.intel.com/products/64614/) under heavy load.

The cabinet fans will probably draw around 5W each- let's call it 50W combined just to be safe. The PSU won't even break a sweat.

I'm doing a lot more with just a quality 620W Corsair PSU, and it's been stable for years.

With the 850W supply you have nothing to worry about at all, but 500W would be sufficient.

[image]

[image]

http://ncix.ca/products/?sku=76035&vpn=CP-9020047-US&manufacture=Corsair

To answer your question about needing a PSU with an additional 4-pin power connector for your 2nd CPU.... the only thing you need to worry about is if the PSU has enough power to support them both (which a 500W supply [does](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1641550)).

You can buy very cheap adapters which convert one of your spare molex connectors into a CPU power connector:

[image]
[image]

Comment: +1, was about to post something similar. I reckon the machine will pull no more than 250W when running flat out.

Comment: It's like asking if a V8 is good enough for a unicycle.

Comment: @austin ..In that case can we go for 400 Watts SMPS?
Please suggest...

Comment: 400W would work fine if it was a good brand and you didn't want to upgrade the server later. But you can get a decent 500W PSU for $39.99, so I wouldn't go for less than 500W myself. http://ncix.ca/products/?minorcatid=1066&po=0&ps=2 Ok, so that's with a $10 instant rebate and a $20 mail-in rebate..... but how hard can a mail-in rebate *really* be? ;)

Comment: @austin...
Can you suggest me a best model of SMPS of 500 W.
Which has 2 pins for CPU? As i am putting 2 processors on our S2400SC2 Mother board?

Comment: Sure- I've updated my answer. The PSU I recommended would be great- you just need an adapter for the extra CPU power connector. Before shipping, they are going for $6 on eBay.

Comment: How about we go for 80 plus GOLD or 80 Plus Platinium series?
Whats the difference, will it improve the reliability?

Anyways ...i will be re-posting a new Question about this.
Please share your knowledge there.

Comment: @austin..
http://superuser.com/questions/613963/power-supply-needed-with-the-below-features-why-80-plus-bronze-gold-platinum