# Power Supply wattage selection. Why 80 plus Bronze, Gold, Platinum?

Tags: cpu, power-supply, productivity

I'm looking at building a file server and looking at getting a quiet, reliable power supply that can power two processors on a single board and run pretty much constantly.

How would I select a power supply that has sufficent wattage for my needs, and what's the difference between the various certifications that power supplies seem to have such as  **80 Plus Bronze**, **80 Plus Gold** and **80 Plus Platinum** ?

The configuration I am running is as follows

- Intel S2400SC2 Motherboard.
- Xeon 2407 Processor x 2 (Dual Processors)
- 8gb x 8 ECC DDR3 RAM
- One 2 TB Seagate HDD.
- 8 cabinet fans fitted for NZXT Switch 810 Cabinet.

Comment: "We want to know the best wattage required for running the above config & we want to know the best & reliable brand of SMPS(Power-Supply) for running 24x7 all day, all night. Also mention its model number." We totally do not do product recommendations on SE. We do often discuss hardware choices on root access however.

Comment: @Journeyman....
I am sorry for asking the brand..
I have changed my entire question based on your recommendation and restrictions. I am sorry i made a mistake previously.Please excuse me for that as i am new-bee. Please read the edited question again and help me out.

Thank you.

Comment: I've edited the question to work better - however there's a [blog](http://superuser.com/questions/613963/power-supply-wattage-selection-why-80-plus-bronze-gold-platinum) post and [another question that cover very similar ground](http://superuser.com/questions/9946/how-to-choose-a-ups-calculate-power-for-a-new-pc). That and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/80_Plus) should cover 99% of what I'd have posted in an answer.

Comment: Unless you are running this as something other than just a "file server" that is a tremendous amount of wasted hardware.  You'd be much better served just buying something like this:http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16856205007

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was literally reading about about this.

[image]

The 80+ rating has to do with the efficiency of your power supply, i've read that some power supplies only get around 50-60% efficiency and lose the rest of the power due to heat. These better power supplies basically are doing less work to get you the power you need, which in turn actually saves you money in the long run. It should be noted that anything passed gold is consider business class equipment and wouldn't serve a normal consumer really any good.

I have a few comments about your file server, i've run a file server for many years. Is this file server personal? Assuming that it is, Why are you buying all this epic hardware to simply share files? You could run a 10 year old computer, and as long as you have 2 gb of ram, with a gb connection, it should run just fine. And to run all this hardware for only 2 TB, it makes no sense to me really, you could put this Hard Drive on your personal computer and simply share it, and as long as your computer is half way decent, you wouldn't see any lag really. Even if they are stream music/movies/docs, whatever.

This power calculator can give you a general idea on how much power you are going to need based on the specs.

http://www.extreme.outervision.com/psucalculatorlite.jsp

Here is my question that i posted yesterday regarding this issue [PC power usage related to power supply](https://superuser.com/questions/644170/pc-power-usage-related-to-power-supply)